# Array of abstract class not allowed

Tags: c++

I have an exercise system designed based on virtual functions. The Exercise class is an abstract class inherited by all other classes.

[image: UML Diagram]

```
class Exercise
{
public:
    Exercise();
    virtual void ExerciseName() = 0;
    virtual void Height();
    virtual void show() = 0;
    virtual void Speed();
    virtual void Weight();
    ~Exercise();
};
```

I would like to populate three sports (instances of the exercises) into an array. This is the code I have tried:

```
Exercise exercises[3];
```

This has the following error:
Error (active)  E0604   array of abstract class "Exercise" is not allowed:  OOP_2017_Q2 H:\OOP_2017_Q2\OOP_2017_Q2\OOP_2017_Q2.cpp  15

How could I populate three exercises into an array, where the base classes uses pure virtual functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a vector of (smart) pointers, for instance:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Exercise>> exercises(3);
```

Then you can use them:

```
exercises[0].reset(new MyExercice);
```